# Does gsutil cp command affect my bandwidth limit quota?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, gsutil

I am looking for a way to get a backup of my firebase storage bucket and found out about gsutil but I want to know that does is count the number of bytes transfer to my local matching in my bandwidth quota?

Really frustrated by firebase support team they are not able to verify my payment info and keep saying that you are suspicious. So I thought it's better to just move my storage to s3 bucket.

Comment: Solve your billing and payment problem first. If you have a problem with Firebase you will also have a problem with Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

> Does `gsutil cp` command affect my bandwidth limit quota?

It does, as using the `gsutil` tool you're still interacting with the GCS, thus its [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) will apply.